# Life Hacks for Urine Guard

Tags: home, substitute-tool, pets

***[Urine Guard](http://www.pet-dog-cat-supply-store.com/shop/index.php?page=shop-flypage-32809&gclid=CNfrh5bYisMCFVAbgQodCI8A7g) is a product for animals that protects from them spraying the walls with Urine. I need a substitute for this, because the original product is to small and my pet jumps and sprays. Also, the product is pretty expensive for something that doesn't fit properly, especially if I bought loads of it.***

- *I already tried Cardboard. But the animal eats that.*
- *My friend said use plastic bags or clothe. But that gets dirty pretty fast and my pet could eat that and choke, so I haven't tried yet and I won't.*

**What are some other methods? I need something that doesn't rust easily and can be cleaned without falling apart.**

One of my main problems is that if I stack the Urine Guard up, there are holes between it that the Urine can fit through.

Comment: I'm curious- what is your pet? I don't know of a household animal that tries to pee on walls so proactively...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest getting a strip of cheap vinyl flooring. This is cut from large rolls at stores such as Lowes, Menards, and Home Depot. Because the piece you need is small you may be able to get it for free, or from scraps. The piece may be twelve feet wide, or the width of the roll, but only two or three feet long depending on how much you get.

If you obtain a wide piece you can have two or three replacements. Putting it outside the cage will allow urine to run down to the floor, while inside will cause urine to run to the bottom of the cage. If the piece goes to the top of the cage there will be no top edge for the animal to gnaw. If the animal does gnaw the side edge, the piece can be replaced, and the animal should stop gnawing after two or three replacements.

Answer (score 1):

***You could try:***

- *Sheet Metal*. The type doesn't matter, but makes sure it is thin and the sharp edges are folded over. Holes can be drilled so that it can be hung with wire. You can even buy a sclice large enough to go as high as the animal jumps.
- Old Vinyl house siding. In some cases the product should have holes already inside of it. This is not large enough, but it is should be cheaper than buying Rabbit Urine Guard if you have some old stuff laying around. Don't use this if the animal chews on the Guard and can reach this, as the animal might eat this.

***Hanging the guard on the outside of the cage promoted the pet not eating it. Also, take the animal for walks and make sure the animal is al-right frequently if the Guard is up high.***